# History.go and browser cache

Tags: redirect, browser-cache

I probably have a very simple question but I can't find the answer anywhere.

When I use a javascript redirect via history.go, how can I make sure the browser doesn't use it's browser cache but actually reloads that page?

Or to put it differently: is it possible to store a page that was previously visited as a string and then redirect users to that page via window.location? Or is that not a solution to my problem?

Comment: Not sure, but you can always use location.reload afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally upto browser implementation. It's same as using browser's back or forward button. Cache is used most probably. Here's a great link. I hope you find your answer there.

[html cache history back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695875/html-cache-history-back)